# using chunked transfer together with content-disposition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, streaming, content-disposition, chunked-encoding

I'm using the following headers to push downloads to the client from a generic path like `/controller_name`:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

However, the browsers seem to be showing the 'Save as' dialog after all data is downloaded. Is there a way to show the dialog as soon as the download is about to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was caused by **buffering** in browsers. I guess the idea is that they let the download start early before presenting the user with a choice. Chrome is even more aggressive and saves short downloads for known types without prompting. There also seems to be a difference whether it happens over localhost or a remote server. For localhost it always buffers for me. This is confusing for developers though :)